# Does a mutex get unlocked when calling notify on a condition variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, condition-variable

I am trying to understand what happens to a mutex when it is used in a condition variable.

In the following example, taken from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

```
int main()
{
    std::queue<int> produced_nums;
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cond_var;
    bool done = false;
    bool notified = false;

    std::thread producer([&]() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
            std::cout << "producing " << i << '\n';
            produced_nums.push(i);
            notified = true;
            cond_var.notify_one();
        }   

        done = true;
        cond_var.notify_one();
    }); 

    std::thread consumer([&]() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        while (!done) {
            while (!notified) {  // loop to avoid spurious wakeups
                cond_var.wait(lock);
            }   
            while (!produced_nums.empty()) {
                std::cout << "consuming " << produced_nums.front() << '\n';
                produced_nums.pop();
            }   
            notified = false;
        }   
    }); 

    producer.join();
    consumer.join();
}
```

The producer thread calls `cond_var.notify_one()` before the mutex gets unlocked. Does the mutex `m` get unlocked when notify is called, or does the notification occurs only when the mutex gets unlocked?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Notifying does not unlock the mutex. You can tell (indirectly) because you don't pass the lock to `notify_one()` the way you do to `wait()`, which does release the mutex while it waits.

On the other side, the notified thread(s) *are* notified "immediately". But they won't necessarily return from `wait()` immediately. Before they can return from `wait()` they must first re-acquire the mutex, so they will block there until the notifying thread releases it.

Answer (score 3):

The lock is being acquired in the constructor and released in the destructor of `std::unique_lock`. From this info you can deduce that the producer releases the lock after the call to `notify_one()` completes.

Comment: exactly what is was looking for :D

Answer (score 0):

For performance reason I suggest to unlock the mutex before to notify other threads.